Creating a Spinbox from 0 to infinity
as the title says, I have a problem following the Youtube tutorial where person creates a Spinbox and allows it to take values from zero to infinity. In their application it works, however when I do it on my computer (Mac) the spinbox shows nothing in the value section (meaning that no numbers show up and by clicking on arrows nothing happens). I assume it might be related to differences in Python versions (mine is 3.12.3 while theirs is 3.7.1), but I am unsure. Mind you, there are no errors appearing during the process of running the program.
Here is the piece of code that I have related to the problem:
numcourses_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(courses_frame, from_ = 0, to = 'infinity')
numcourses_spinbox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

I have tried to look for the mistakes in my code by comparing my results with person's video and also to change 'infinity' string to integer number, which has worked for me as a solution. However, writing manualy the borderline for the amount of courses is not very efficient for me.
Here is a minimal reproductive example:

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Data Entry Form')

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

courses_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame)
courses_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'news', padx = 20, pady = 20)

numcourses_label = tkinter.Label(courses_frame, text = '# Completed Courses')
numcourses_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

numcourses_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(courses_frame, from_ = 0, to = 'infinity')
numcourses_spinbox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()

Here is the link to the video (timestamp is 31:50):
https://youtu.be/vusUfPBsggw?si=BstmvEOqld7_-yYc

I wonder if this is a Mac issue, because this works for me in Python 3.11.3 under Windows.

Please create a tiny but complete [mcve]. However, the to value needs to be a floating point number and 'infinity' is not a floating point number

if you follow some tutorial then show link to tutorial - maybe it is very old tutorial and it can't work with newest Python or Tkinter. And show link in question, not in comments - more people will see it, so more people may help you.

if you have courses on list then you can use to = len(courses) to get amount of courses - and you don't have to write it manually.

The values for from_ and to need to be floating point numbers. 'infinity' is not a floating point number. If you want to specify infinity in a reliable way, use float('inf'):
numcourses_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(courses_frame, from_ = 0, to = float('inf'))


Thank you for your suggestion, I have added minimal reproductible example as you reqiuested and tried your method with float('inf'). Unfortunately, it did not work.

'infinity' is a valid float number same as 'inf'.
